# Mobile Connect Import CSV File

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, field-mapping

I am trying and importing a file in a new standard list but I am unable to map by either header rows or manually since the system imports all data into one column.

The CSV file is comma delimited and contains these columns:

- `_MobileNumber`
- `_LastName`
- `_Email`
- `_CountryCode`
- `_ContactKey`

Do I need to configure anything ?

Comment: Are these the column of the DE you are importing into?

Answer (score 1):

You have the right columns based on the outline here: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/mobileconnect/contacts/import_contacts_to_a_standard_list_or_all_contacts/prepare_file_for_import/

However, if it maps it all into same row it seems that there must be an error in your source file. You should be able to select manual and then map:

- CountryCode to Locale (believe this is the name for the column)
- MobileNumber to MobileNumber
- ContactKey to ContactKey